# How to reduce space between letter and subscript when using \mathbf

Tags: fonts, vector

I have simplified the question to be more clear.

How to add a macro in preamble to change any occurrence of pattern `\mathbf{foo}_{boo}` to become `\mathbf{foo}_{\!boo}`

For example, given this file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%---> need macro here

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\mathbf{V}_{D}  & =\mathbf{V}_{C}+\boldsymbol{\omega}_{CD}\times\mathbf{r}_{D/C}
\end{align}
But we also see that $\mathbf{V}_{D}$ can be written as

\end{document}
```

Then by only modifying the preamble, I'd like the PDF generated be such that as if I have written this

```
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\mathbf{V}_{\!D}  & =\mathbf{V}_{\!C}+\boldsymbol{\omega}_{CD}\times\mathbf{r}_{\!D/C}
\end{align}
But we also see that $\mathbf{V}_{\!D}$ can be written as

\end{document}
```

Using macro or other Latex trick in the preamble only. I can't edit the code inside the document or use editor to do global search/replace.

note: I am using *lualatex* to compile to pdf on texlive.

Comment: You can adjust the space manually.

Comment: Just write `\mathbf{V}_{\!D}`, `\mathbf{V}_{\!C}`, etc. `\!` stands for "negative thinspace".

Comment: @Mico thanks. Is it possible to add this as some macro in preamble? I do not want to modify the code itself everywhere. Something that will modify it globally? I added this to the question to clarify.

Comment: Why don't you want to modify the code? All you'd have to do is do a global search-and-replace of `\mathbf{V}_{` for `\mathbf{V}_{\!`.

Comment: @Mico I use SW to generate the latex. SW have option to make something bold, but have no option to tell it to make subscript thin space. And I can't keep doing global search and replace each time on each file generated. But if there is a solution I can add to preamble, then it will be automatically done.

Comment: You should have tagged your posting with `scientific-workplace`, by the way. Not being able to manipulate the underlying LaTeX code is a serious limitation, in my view, and it should make you reconsider your choice of software in a big way.

Comment: @Mico SW is not the point here. Even if I am not using SW. Iam looking for a solution I could use globally. Suppose I have files written before, and now I want to change the spacing on the bold letter subscript to thin. Having to edit 100's of files and manually changing them is not practical.  But I can modify the preamble once. May be add some smart macro? Latex is very good at making these macros which will do automatic substitution.

Comment: Well you can write a macro so you say `$\svector{D} \svector{C}$` etc. Is that what you mean? It's just replacement text, after all. `\newcommand*\svector[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{V}_{\!#1}}}` or whatever.

Comment: Are you saying that you cannot have your “external software” (whatever it is) to generate code that contains, say, `\vector{V}`, as @cfr suggests, instead of `\mathbf{V}`?

Comment: @GuM the software SW generates pure Latex. So I can generate anything I want. It just not easy to tell it to add thin space between the subscript the vector in the GUI each time. So I can generate `\mathbf{V}_{C}` or `\mathbf{A}_{D}` etc.. from the GUI to the file. I just need a macro to change these to `\mathbf{V}_{\!C}` or `\mathbf{A}_{\!D}` everyhwere there is this pattern: `\mathbf{x}_{y}`. But want to use a macro in preamble to do this automatically when I compile the file using texlive. I am not good with Latex macros. This might be trivial to do otherwise.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to change also `\mathbf{A}_{D}` into `\mathbf{A}_{\!D}`?  I wouldn’t say that the subscript needs to be “tucked” to the left in this case.  But is there a way to tell the software to represent, in the generated LaTeX code, a bold letter with a subscript in the form of a custom command instead of using `\mathbf`?

Comment: I think LuaTeX can do this, but I’m not an expert: I’m writing this comment only to suggest you that you include the information about the typesetting engine you are using, since the fact that you are using `luatex` *is* relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how many things this might break:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \mathbf{V}_{D}  & =\mathbf{V}_{C}+\mathbf{\omega}_{CD}\times\mathbf{r}_{D/C}
\end{align}
But we also see that $\mathbf{V}_{D}$ can be written as

\let\oldmathbf\mathbf
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\mathbf}[1]{\oldmathbf{#1}\@ifnextchar_{\msubscript}{}}
\def\msubscript_#1{_{\!#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{align}
  \mathbf{V}_{D}  & =\mathbf{V}_{C}+\mathbf{\omega}_{CD}\times\mathbf{r}_{D/C}
\end{align}
But we also see that $\mathbf{V}_{D}$ can be written as

\end{document}
```

We peek ahead after having set `\mathbf{.}` to see if there's a `_` in the input stream and condition to insert a `\!`.

Comment: Thanks, that works great. I made typo btw, I meant to use `\boldsymbol{\omega}` in my example, instead of `\mathbf{\omega}`. But this has nothing to do with your solution. Just want to point that out. Will correct my MWE.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to add `\!` to every subscript following something in `\mathbf`: the example of `\mathbf{A}_{\!D}` should be sufficient.

Rather, define your own macro and check the last or unique letter in its argument for deciding whether adding `\!` or nothing or another spacing command (I used A, V, W and Y for the example). Also superscripts are to be taken care of.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\vect}{ m e{_^} }{\innervect{#1}{#2}{#3}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\innervect}{mmm}
 {
  \mathbf{#1}
  \IfValueT{#2}% there is a subscript
   {
    \str_case_x:nnF { \tl_item:nn { #1 } { -1 } }
     {
      {V}{\sb{\!#2}}
      {W}{\sb{\!#2}}
      {Y}{\sb{\mspace{-1mu}#2}}
     }
     {\sb{#2}}
   }
  \IfValueT{#3}% there is a superscript
   {
    \str_case_x:nnF { \tl_item:nn { #1 } { -1 } }
     {
      {A}{\sp{\!#3}}
     }
     {\sp{#3}}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\vect{V}_{D}+\vect{A}_{D} \mid \mathbf{V}_{D}+\mathbf{A}_{D}$

$\vect{V}^{2}+\vect{A}^{2} \mid \mathbf{V}^{2}+\mathbf{A}^{2}$

$\vect{V}_{D}^{2}+\vect{A}_{D}^{2} \mid
   \mathbf{V}_{D}^{2}+\mathbf{A}_{D}^{2}$

\end{document}
```

[image]